# Locating Hyperlink with selenium webdriver with Java

Tags: hyperlink, click, selenium-webdriver

I have the below href link with the + sign. I don't have the Id or name for this. Is there any i can locate and click this [+] link. Can anybody please share the code.

```
<td class="expandCollapseLink"><a href="" onclick="toggleIds(889358, this); return false;">[+]  </a></td>
```

Comment: User want code already done by someone

Answer (score 1):

You can use an element's inner text to locate the element.  Try using the following XPATH to locate the link:
//td[@class='expandCollapseLink']/a[contains(text(),'[+]')]

You may find this to be a useful cross-reference for different XPATH/CSS selectors in the future.  I use it very frequently:  https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Answer (score 0):

//td[@class='expandCollapseLink']/a should be all the xpath selector you need.
//td[@class='expandCollapseLink']/a[contains(@onclick,"toggleIds")] should also work and be a bit more specific.